# Merging an array of object in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, merge

I have an array of object like

```
[{ a=1, b=4, c=4, d=6}, { a=1, b=4, c=4, d=6}, …],[{ a=1, b=4, c=4, d=6}, { a=1, b=4, c=4, d=6}, …],[{ a=1, b=4, c=4, d=6}, { a=1, b=4, c=4, d=6}, …]
```

and would like it to merge into one unique array like this

```
[{ a=1, b=4, c=4, d=6}, { a=1, b=4, c=4, d=6}, { a=1, b=4, c=4, d=6}, { a=1, b=4, c=4, d=6}, { a=1, b=4, c=4, d=6}, { a=1, b=4, c=4, d=6}, …]
```

I need a unique array in order to render it in a Flatlist.

Comment: this is going to give a syntax error. do you mean `a:1` and not `a=1` ?

Comment: do you have all array of objects in one array or object ?

Answer (score 0):

## Use Flat

To make your array 1 level deep use the array method flat

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, [3, 4]];
arr1.flat(); 
// [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

## Use Set

To make an array unique convert it to a `Set`

```
const myArray = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];
const unique = [...new Set(myArray)]; 

// unique is ['a', 1, 2, '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion, my bad... I should have explained myself better.

Before I was retrieving just page1 of an API which contained 20 items like in this format

```
[{"popularity": 25.41, "name": "Wan Peng","id": 2187124},{"popularity": 25.238,"name": "Jason Statham”,"id": 976},…{"popularity": 24.784,"name": "Henry Cavill","id": 73968}]
```

With that I was able to render the data in a Flatlist easily.

Now I'm fetching 20 pages by looping my API Fetch and concatenating the result

```
total_results = total_results + resData.results;
```

my logs now looks like this

```
RESDATA TOTAL RESULTS: [object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]
```

and I'd like it to merge it all in one like this

```
RESDATA TOTAL RESULTS: [object Object]
```

Hopefully I managed to clarify my issue a bit better now.